# Does update from TestFlight works the same as the update from Appstore

Tags: ios, upgrade, testflight

We have an app which is already published to the app store (v 1.1) and now we wants to release a new build with some updates (v 1.2). We have uploaded the new build to test flight.

We wants to make upgrade test of v 1.2 over v 1.1 but we are not sure about what happens when we download app from TestFlight (v 1.2) over the already downloaded app from AppStore(v 1.1).

will it behave same as the app update from the Appstore? or we need to do something else for upgrade test.

According to apple we can upgrade test using adhoc builds.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323